# Finding optimal 2-center clustering from max-diameter 2-clustering

Tags: cluster-analysis, computational-geometry

Given a set of points in Euclidean space, we want to partition them into 2 clusters such that the maximum diameter of all the clusters gets minimized. The definition of cluster diameter is given below:

1. The diameter of a cluster is the diameter of the minimum enclosing circle of the points on that cluster. (2-center clustering)
2. The diameter of a cluster is the maximum possible distance between any two points on that cluster. (max diameter 2-clustering)

Consider, we have an exact solution for max diameter 2-clustering. We know that these two clusterings are not equivalent. Is there any way we can find the exact 2-center clustering from the exact solution of max diameter 2-clustering?